# Calculating the difference between the count of two date fields

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

I have data that is provided to me that includes the routed date and the service restoration date.  From that it's pretty easy to generate a pivot table that generates a table with the date of the month, then a count of received tickets (routed), and the count of closed tickets.  I'm trying to generate a calculated field (Pivot -> Options -> Fields, Items & Sets -> Calculated Field) to derive the delta.

When I use `=Received - Closed`, I get the difference in date rather than the delta in the counts.  Can anyone point me in a direction on how I may calculate it?  If it was static content it would be easy peasy, but I'm not getting the knack of doing this with a pivot table.  Also I could achieve something similar with a `countif` type command and run it from a static calendar type table (which is what I'll probably end up doing if this ends up being a dead end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution, you can copy the pivot table and paste it as values in the new sheet. Do you math on values instead of on pivot.

I don't know if formatting your results in the pivot as `NUMBER` would help.. But you can try that as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably have to end up doing that or setting up a calendar type table and doing a countif using the date for the comparison.  Then just bake it out as a monthly report.  Was trying to shoot for a 'monkey presses the button' type report.

Comment: Well, you can record a macro to make a vba to do it all

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to determine a way outside of what was mentioned above by Andrew.  I've set up a static date list for the calendar month and then use a series of countifs instead of a pivot table to generate the output.  Thanks to all who reviewed the question and to Andrew for his responses.